# .class expected (Newbie on java)

Tags: java

I don't know why this cannot run, the error on "num = Integer.parseInt (args[]) ;"

```
class CommandLine {
    public static void main (String args [])
    {
        int num ;
        num = Integer.parseInt (args[]) ;
        if (num>=100)
        { 
        } else {
            System.out.println("Number is less than 100");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you intend `args[]` to mean?

Comment: `args[]` is a valid variable name. `args` is an String array. I would advise you to learn variables and arrays in java.

Comment: An array is not an integer value which is what `parseInt` method expects. But, even if you do something like `args[0]` you probably didn't even pass any command-line arguments when you ran the class. SO, you will end up with another error.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam: No, `args[]` isn't a valid variable name. `args` is a valid variable name, which is permitted to be declared in a declaration such as `String args []`... the name is still `args` though.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes it was not i missed a "not" i meant "not valid"

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `args[]`, you need to pass a command-line argument when you run the class. For example, if you are running from command prompt, you will need to do something like this:

```
java CommandLine 100
```

In your code, you could do something like this

```
class CommandLine {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        int num = Integer.parseInt (args[0]) ;
        if (num>=100)
        { 
            System.out.println("You entered ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Number is less than 100");
        }
    }
}
```

Which will result in displaying `You entered 100` on the console. If you are running from an IDE like Eclipse, you will need to set up the command-line argument through the "*Run Configurations*" menu. Then, you enter (space-separated) arguments in the "*Program arguments*" text area.

[image]

In IntelliJ, you do the same through the "*Modify run configuration*" menu

[image]

The argument array `args[]` in a class' main method is built by the JVM. It is a string of command-line arguments that are passed to the executed class.  The JVM parses out the command line instruction and will gather any and all values after the class name and will create that `args` array. If you pass nothing to the program, then the array will be empty.

An command-line instruction like

```
java MyClass Hello World Welcome to Java
```

builds a `String` array with 5 values.

Comment: The parameter is just called `args`. The `[]` is part of the type information - it's best not to refer to it as `args[]` as if that's actually the name. (I'd also strongly recommend using `String[] args` instead of `String args[]` in the first place, to avoid this sort of confusion.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Honestly, I don't know if the OP even understand what that means. I was trying to do my best to write it in a way the OP would understand.

Comment: @hfontanez: But in doing so, I think you're running the risk of further reinforcing the idea that `args[]` is the name of the variable, which it isn't. I would say that addressing that - explaining that the name of a variable and its type are really separate concepts, and that writing `String[] args` instead make that clearer - is rather more important than showing how to provide command line options in an IDE.